# Can I create Union of classes

Tags: c++, class, unions

I have two classes for communication that will never exist at the same time but both will be in use.

Example:

```
class CommA
{
public:
    void SendA();
    ...
private:
    ProtocolA a;
    ...
}

class CommB
{
public:
    void SendB();
    ...
private:
    ProtocolB b;
    ...
}
```

Is it possible to hold them in Union to save memory?

```
union CommAB
{
    CommA a;
    CommB b;
}
```

Comment: The equivalent in modern C++ is [std::variant](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/variant)

Comment: Sure, although [`std::variant`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/variant) is to be preferred.

Comment: Did you try? Did you encounter any problems?

Comment: Yes, but you'll need a custom constructor and a destructor for the union, which can be tricky to write properly. If you have to ask, then your best bet is to use `std::variant`, which acts exactly as a union with custom constructors, destructors, and some safety mechanisms.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [`std::variant`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/variant) was already raised by others in comments and answers.  I'll explain why it is the recommended approach.

There is an important thing to know about unions:  only one member of a union can be active at any time. If you create an `AB` object, it's either `a` or `b`, and if you access the wrong one, it's UB.  How do you know which one is the active one?  Fortunately the standard provides some guarantees: if classes of all union-members start with the same common members, you can access those safely.  The usual trick is then to have a first member in all the classes of the union to determine which is the active one. Another issue can be when you have an active member and want to change it.

The advantage of the `variant` is that it takes care of these practical aspects without you having to worry, and without having to adjust the classes of the members.

Since you are looking for space:  the union takes the space of its largest member.   So if you have to add a common extra member in your classes to track the active union member, your union will be larger that either the initial A or B. The variant does the work for you, so it will be larger as well.